# Laravel Form Displaying data

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I created an array of users in my homeController which then renders its data in the home.blade.php file. However when I try to submit the form I get an error that says: **Undefined variable: usersArray**

Here's my **home.blade.php:**

```
{!! Form::open(array('id' => 'activateForm')) !!}

{!! csrf_field() !!}

<div>

<div class="home-rounded-border  center-content">
        <input type = "checkbox" id = "checkAll" />Select All<span style="padding-left: 310px;font-weight: bold;">Email</span><br/>
        @foreach($usersArray as $key => $value)
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxUser{{$key}}" name="user-name-checkbox{{$key}} ">{{$value}}
                <input type = "email" class="styled-text  rounded" name = "name" id = "customer-name-inputField{{$key}}" placeholder=""/><br/><br/>
            </li>
        </ul>
        @endforeach

    <center><input type = "submit" class="sign-in-button"value = "Submit"/></center>

    </br>
    <div id="statusMsg" style="margin: 0px 40px 0px 40px; background-color: #ffffff;"></div>

    <ul><li class="logout"><a href="logout"><span>Logout</span></a></li></ul>

</div>

<br/><br/>
 </div>
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: If the error occures when the form is submitted then you need to show the method that handles that

Comment: Also, let's see your routes.php file

Comment: which one method in your controller handles post request on the same url?

Comment: Please add controller code also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define usersArray in post function too. Which handls the post request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `<input type = "email" class="styled-text  rounded" name = "name" id = "customer-name-inputField{{$key}}}}" placeholder=""/><br/><br/>`, you added 4x `}` after $key

Comment: I just got rid of those extra }} but It still doesn't work :(